# How can I access a controller (from an external file)'s scope in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my controllers in a separate file named controller.js and I have my app.js set up like so

```
angular.module('WeCompeteApp', [
    'WeCompeteApp.controllers',
    'WeCompeteApp.services',
    'WeCompeteApp.utilities',
    'WeCompeteApp.filters',
    'ui.router',
    'ngSanitize'
])
```

So I have a controller in my controllers file named `ChallengesController` that I am trying to include in my directive to access one of its functions.

My directive looks like

```
.directive('whenScrolled', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ChallengesController',
        scope: {
            challenges: '=',
            page: '=',
            filter: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ChallengesCtrl) {

            var raw = elm[0];

            elm.bind('scroll', function() {

                if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {

                    console.log('scrolled to bottom');

                    if (scope.challenges.length >= 20) {

                        ChallengesCtrl.getChallenges(scope.page, 20, scope.filter);

                    }

                }

            });

        }

    };

}]);
```

But when I try to run the function I get that `ChallengesCtrl` is undefined so I'm not sure if this is set up properly.  Any help is greatly appreciated and if more info is needed, please just say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `link` and `controller` share the same scope:

Remove the injection of `ChallengesCtrl` from `link` and change:

```
ChallengesCtrl.getChallenges(scope.page, 20, scope.filter);
```

TO

```
scope.getChallenges(scope.page, 20, scope.filter);
```

The only time you have that controller injection in `link` is when you `require` another directive controller

Comment: But how does this directive know which controller to access?

Comment: because you told it which one. Now there might also be some confusion if the controller is already part of the view .... link and controller do very similar things and are only related to the specific directive. I that controller is actually the parent of this directive...will need a different approach

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, I'm an idiot I forgot the `controller:` part was still there.  That worked, thank you very much!

Comment: is `ChallengesController` the parent though? Will have to pass functions into isloated scope if that's what you are trying to do

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, this directive is in my app,js file and my controller is in a separate controllers.js file.

Comment: that's fine...what i mean is the controller running other parts of the view already? In directive `controller` does not mean `parent`

Comment: I think it's the parent, sorry, I'm fairly new to Angular.  I have my route set up like ```.state('challenges', {
            url: '/challenges',
            views: {
                'main': {
                    controller: 'ChallengesController',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/challenges.html'
                }
            }
        });```  and the directive is on an html element in the challenges.html template.

Comment: ok....in that case, you need to pass that function name into your isolated scope the same way you pass in other attributes... or ...possibly you don't need isolated scope and then directive does share parent scope